# Do Vedas & Grihya sutras prescribe rules only for a Brahmin?

Tags: vedas, rituals, dharma-shastras, vedic-rituals, grihya-sutra

Are the mantras, rituals etc. from Vedas available only for Brahmins? Does it mean that castes other than Brahmins do not have any prescribed rules of life and rituals?

Comment: @UdayKrishna People from other castes cannot become brahmins. The only instance of this that is known is that of Viswamitra. @ P.R. Ramachander - No religion prescribes rules of life for all castes, asramas and for both genders.

Comment: @moonstar2001 Do you believe in **birth based Caste / Varna or Guna based Varna**?

Comment: The Gruhya Sutras give rules for all 4 varnas but most of the time they describe rules for first 3 varnas Dwijas.

Comment: @UdayKrishna - I agree with  your views "only a “Brahma jnani” qualifies as a “Brahmin” ,  but then the question will arise that wht.  abt.people who are still learning or at various stages of attending bhrama-gyan.In which category they are  in or varna.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Birth-based caste cannot be discounted. It is a result of penance of the jeeva as well as his forefathers. If after having gained a "noble" birth, the person does not respect it but lives in a way that adharmic, then he becomes a fallen individual.

Comment: @P.R. Ramachander - I meant, Hindu religion <b>does</b> prescribe rules of life for all castes, asramas and for both genders. There was a typo in my previous note.

Comment: @UdayKrishna While it is true that a brahma j~nAni is a brahmana, a brahmana by birth has performed penance over several lifetimes to attain the state of brahma j~nAna and therefore is closer to it  in general. This does not mean brahma j~nAna is not available to people of other castes. It is available to all jIvas even to animals.

Answer (score 5):

No the injunctions are not just for the Brahmins. **The Grihya Sutras in fact prescribe rules for the first three Varna even though the Parashar Smriti actually mentions the roles and responsibilities of all the four castes.**

As mentioned in the [ÂPASTAMBA'S YAGÑA-PARIBHÂSHÂ-SÛTRAS](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe30/sbe30119.htm):

[image]

Again the [SANKHAYAN GRIHYA SUTRA Khanda 28](http://www.hinduwebsite.com/sacredscripts/hinduism/grihya/sankhayana.asp#1.1) states:

> 1. After one year the Kûdâkarman (i.e. the tonsure of the child's head);
> 2. Or in the third year;
> 3. In the fifth for a **Kshatriya;**
> 4. In the seventh for a **Vaisya.**
> 5. Having placed the fire (in the outer hall; see chap. 5, 2)—

Again in the ADHYÂYA II, KHANDA 1.

> 1. In the eighth year after the conception let him initiate a **Brâhmana,**
> 2. With an antelope-skin,
> 3. Or in the tenth year after the conception.
> 4. In the eleventh year after the conception a **Kshatriya** with the skin of a spotted deer,
> 5. In the twelfth year after the conception a **Vaisya** with a cow-hide.
> 6. Until the sixteenth year the time has not passed for a Brâhmana,
> 7. Until the twenty-second for a Kshatriya,
> 8. Until the twenty-fourth for a Vaisya.
>      9 9. After that (time has passed), they become patitasâvitrîka (men who have lost their right of learning the Sâvitrî).

Further verses also mention such stuff:

15. The girdle of a **Brâhmana** (shall be) made of Muñga grass,
16. That of a **Kshatriya** (shall be) a bowstring,
17. That of a **Vaisya** a woollen thread.
18. The staff of a **Brâhmana** (shall be) made of Palâsa or of Bilva wood,
19. That of a **Kshatriya** of Nyagrodha wood,
20. That of a **Vaisya** of Udumbara wood.
21. That of the **Brâhmana** shall reach the tip of the nose,
22. That of the **Kshatriya** the forehead,
23. That of the **Vaisya** the hair.
24. Or all (sorts of staffs are to be used) by (men of) all (castes).
25. Whatsoever (the student) wears at his initiation, is at the disposal of the teacher.

**Hence we can see that the rituals and advice in these scriptures are meant not just for the Brahmins.**

Comment: Nice to see your interest in Vedas :)

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53977/agama-and-tantra @Dr

Comment: @RakeshJoshi yes I find them quite fascinating :) It is especially interesting to see how a single verse in the Vedas can contain an entire Puranic story!